# Open Id Connect : well know endpoint location

Tags: angular, openid-connect

I have an API, some JavaScript SPAs and they can be configured to use an OIDC server. This one can change over time.

I want to share the url of the OIDC server to use in the API instead of updating each app and API configuration on each change.

Is it a good idea to provide an endpoint which just "redirect/ proxy" the .well-known endpoint from the OIDC server ? It would provide all the necessary information. Is there a standard/RFC for this need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t believe there is an RFC for that.
You could expose an endpoint that returns the OIDC server URL plus other required configurations.
This way, client applications can retrieve the configuration at runtime.